# How can I automatically change a TODO agenda item/task to PROGRESS when clocking in?

Tags: org-mode

Is there a way to automatically change the TODO keyword into PROGRESS when I clock in to an agenta item/task?  If so, how?  (OK, this isn't a big deal, I currently press `I t p` to achieve this, but it would be nice to have (and save 50% on keystrokes when including the Shift for `I`).)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should set `org-clock-in-switch-to-state` to the intended state:

```
(setq org-clock-in-switch-to-state "PROGRESS")
```

> Documentation: Set task to a special todo state while clocking it. The
>   value should be the state to which the entry should be switched.

Comment: Very nice!  This also alludes to how to set the todo state to `WAITING` when clocking out... :-)

Answer (score 1):

Sacha Chua achieves this by doing the reverse, clocking-in when the state is changed to 'progress' (instead of changing state when clocking-in):
https://sachachua.com/blog/2007/12/clocking-time-with-emacs-org/

Hopefully that helps!